# Why I can't perform this simple JavaScript test program into a JSFiddle?

Tags: javascript, alert, jsfiddle

I am pretty new in JavaScript and I have a litle doubt.

I have created this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AndreaNobili/1up938xf/

I have defined only the JavaScript function that perform a simple sum (no HTML) and that show the result into a popup by an alert

```
var add = function(x, y) {

  z = z + y;
  return z;
}

var sum = add(2, 3);

alert(sum);
```

The problem is that when I try to run this test application I can't see anything. Why? What am I missing?

Comment: I think JSFiddle and JSBin block the `alert()` function for safety reasons. Try `console.log()` and open up your dev console to see test output

Comment: [Learn how to debug JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty easy to fix, actually.

One: your adding function doesn't actually add correctly. It should be, `x + y` not `z + y`

```
function(x, y) {

  z = x + y;
  return z;
}
```

It was causing an error because you were trying to use a variable you never declared or assigned (`z + y`)

Answer (score 4):

That is probably because you are calling z instead of x and tbe first time, z is no defined yet

Answer (score 2):

> ReferenceError: z is not defined

and your missing a `var`. Define `z` first or (more likely) use `x` instead:

```
var add = function(x, y) {
  var z = x + y;
  return z;
}

var sum = add(2, 3);

alert(sum);
```

And here is a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1up938xf/1/

Answer (score 0):

You are using "z = z + y;" but you want "z = x + y;"

First one causes a JS error and the alert is not shown